# ModuleNotFoundError on own made model folder

Tags: python, code-coverage, python-3.10, coverage.py

Doing some testing on my own game that I am using to learn python. I am attempting some Code Coverage using the CoveragePY that I have installed via PyCharm's Package Manager. Wrote up my tests, right clicked the "testing" directory and opened in Terminal and ran "coverage run test_game_data.py" and instantly get a "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mode'" error - now since I am using MVC I have my coding files within model, view or controller directories with only database, save games and testing outside of these.

The exact error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[user]\Documents\Documents 2\Code Repo's\PythonGame\testing\test_map_tile.py", line 3, in <module>
    from model.game_data import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'
```

As you can imagine my test is trying to reference a file in model, the game_data.py file to be exact. So I just have a simple `from model.game_data import *` in my test, this is applicable to all my other test files that I have. I thought maybe it didn't know what the asterisk was all about so I changed it to the class name `GameData` with it still having the same error. I also thought this might be because I don't have an `__init__.py` file but adding this, both blank and populated with my imports, didn't fix this issue

A lot of what I found to resolve this has been based around premade packages like Numpy and Pandas but none of these solutions seem to have an effect on my error. Whats the best course of action for me to take so that I can get my Code Coverage working?

Folder Structure:

```
Game
|__ model
|__ view
|__ controller
|__ database
|__ tests
```

Comment: Where is your module located?

Comment: whoops, forgot to add the Folder Structure to my og post. GameData is under model which is under Game and test_game_data is under tests which is under Game

Answer (score 0):

Go in the terminal to the folder `Game`, and run `coverage run -m tests.test_game_data`.

The issue is that you're not treating `Game` like a package, you just enter the tests folder and in that directory, `model` does not exist. `-m` does exactly that.